# Unable to modify Jenkins job configurations and build trigger stopped working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Using jenkins version 2.277.3

I tried to modify an old jenkins freestyle job configuration and it was not possible to save it after the changes i made as the save and apply buttons doesnt respond and work. Then I tried the same by creating a new freestyle job same thing happened.

Other issue is when a commit is made the pipeline used to get triggered using PollSCM feature. now the pipelines stopped to trigger build on commits. All the configurationss are set properly.

Comment: Read the [upgrade guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.277/#configuration-form-modernization) and follow the procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade all your plugins and it should work again. An easy way to do this is to create a pipeline job with the following code

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;

pm = Jenkins.instance.pluginManager

uc = Jenkins.instance.updateCenter
updated = false
progress = 0
updates = 0

pm.plugins.each { plugin ->
  if (uc.getPlugin(plugin.shortName).version != plugin.version) {
      updates = updates + 1
  }
}

pm.plugins.each { plugin ->
  if (uc.getPlugin(plugin.shortName).version != plugin.version) {
    update = uc.getPlugin(plugin.shortName).deploy(true)
    println "updating ${plugin.shortName}:${plugin.version} -> ${uc.getPlugin(plugin.shortName)?.version}"
    update.get()
    progress = progress + 1
    updated = true
  }
}
if (updated) {
  println "${progress}/${pm.plugins.size()} Restarting"
  Jenkins.instance.doSafeRestart(null);
}
```

Comment: Nice script. However, I'd like to suggest to make it friendlier, it should report the existing and updated version `echo "updating ${plugin.shortName}:${plugin.version} -> ${uc.getPlugin(plugin.shortName)?.version}"`, so it can act as a changelog. Also suggest making sure latest version is not null, just in case plugin has been removed or does not exist in Update Center.

Comment: The OP's basic issue was he did not follow the [documented update procedure](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.277/#upgrading-to-jenkins-lts-2-277-1), *"Use the Plugin Manager to update plugins affected by configuration form modernization immediately after upgrading to Jenkins 2.277.1"*, which is also achievable from the `/pluginManager/` page, **Updates** tab,  **All** button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: To be fair, the update procedure is not something I normally read... TLDR, only in case of problems I might have a look. But I didn't notice the "All" button in the updates tab before, hence I used the script